# Can I set a password on an existing dmg?

Tags: password, dmg

I am just wondering if it's possible to set a password to existing dmg image. There is no such option at Disk Utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it by first selecting the DMG in Disk Utilty. Then go to Images>Change Password.

[image: Change Password - Disk Utility]
It will prompt you for the password.
[image: prompt for password - Disk Utility]
Then, it'll ask you for a new password for the DMG.
[image: New password prompt]

Comment: @com File? It's under the Images menu, unless you have an older OS...

Comment: This does not seem to work under Mavericks though. The Images menu does not include the Change Password… item. What now?

Comment: @Aller, go to File->Change Password like the user above mentioned.

Comment: If this option does not appear to you and File->Change Password appears disabled (as happening to me), check Nigel Redmon answer below, `hdiutil chpass <image>`, it worked for me (if you copy it from here, do not forget to upvote his answer anyway)

Answer (score 5):

Open the Terminal application, and type

`hdiutil chpass <image>`

where `<image>` is the disk image path. You can type "hdiutil chpass " and drag the file to the terminal window to complete the path. The disk image need not be mounted. The command will prompt you for the current password, then for the new password, followed by the new password again for verification.

Comment: macOS Monterey 12.7.2, Disk Utilty, I can see File->Change Password option, but it appears disabled for a certain file of mine, at least (not sure about others)... Therefore, I just tried this command you mention, `hdiutil chpass <image>`, and it worked for me, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you add a password and then add disc passwords now

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review